# How to run python scripts in one computer in LAN and send the output to other system in same LAN?

Tags: python, django, lan

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471173/accessing-django-project-in-lan-systems) solution and tried there accepted answer but it not worked.

I have Django project in desktop destination and Apache24 installed in C drive. But I want to use this Django project on other system connected to Same LAN. I am using window 10.

I have tried all the solution i found in SO as follows but nothing worked
such as:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost','192.168.1.8']
```

Making debug = `true/false`
adding IP address in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`
But nothing worked.

Please help in making/give direction how i can make a connection to get access to Django project via access of LAN.

Let system A run the django application by the development server

```
(venv) C:\Users\Carthaginian\Desktop\rp-portfolio\personal_portfolio>python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.8:8080
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 10, 2019 - 12:00:18
Django version 2.2.4, using settings 'personal_portfolio.settings'
Starting development server at http://192.168.1.8:8080/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

**Now How system B can connect to this URL http://192.168.1.8:8080/ via LAN?**

Below is some structure.
[image]

**This below is edit**
My Django web application is working fine in my system as follows:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Carthaginian\Desktop\rp-portfolio\personal_portfolio>python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 11, 2019 - 10:41:21
Django version 2.2.4, using settings 'personal_portfolio.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[11/Sep/2019 10:43:32] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5196
[11/Sep/2019 10:43:33] "GET /blog/5/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4897
[11/Sep/2019 10:43:35] "GET /blog/Softwares/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2483
[11/Sep/2019 10:43:37] "GET /projects/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2774
[11/Sep/2019 10:43:37] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5196
[11/Sep/2019 10:43:40] "GET /blog/Computer%20Networks/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2503
[11/Sep/2019 10:43:41] "GET /projects/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2774
```

Comment: Can you able to ping your IP address from other computer connected in the same LAN?

Comment: Let me check it

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "access"? Do you wish to share files between the two systems? Do you wish to access the other machine by some specific protocol (SFTP, HTTPS, etc.)? (In any case ping would be the first step)

Comment: I want to serve the Django application running on one system and use on another system connected via same LAN

Comment: Also is there any way that to get the output of python script which i run via window command prompt can be used by another system in same local area network and from another system just enter the input and run the python script on my system

Answer (score 0):

you can use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:Port_No` on the host computer. It will bind your IP address to server address and make it accessible to all the other computers on the same network. On other computers now you can access this server by using your_ip:Port_NO.

Comment: ok let me see it? Also i am using django web application which i run on my system, and i want this web application to be accessible on other system connected to same LAN

Comment: This solution is for Django application. I have been using it for past one month without any problem.

Comment: If i ping from other system to my system it is saying timed out

Comment: also i have some query regarding python that if a python script is run by my system let's say web crawler crawls data and saves csv in my system then can same be done with django to crawls and send the data to other system

Comment: i tried this `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` but it is not working

Comment: Also I have updated the `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost','0.0.0.0','192.168.1.8','192.168.1.12']` in file `settings.py`

Comment: Is we need to include port number in client system in URL or just IP address

Comment: can this is running in virtual environment is the problem of not executing the application in client system